# Application not working after deployment to Appengine standard environment

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, deployment, djangoappengine

My python(3.5) and django(2.1) app runs good locally but after I have deployed it on App engine, It gives me error by clicking on links.

> ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'chaipani.django_site' doesn't exist")
>   raise_mysql_exception (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py:109)

Plese tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: Seems as if you are using a local database, when running locally, but you do not have configured in Django an external database. For example, considering Cloud SQL as an external database, you would need something like [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#understanding_the_code)

Comment: I have made an instance. Followed the appengine  docs step by step and did everything. Should I make a database separately on app engine? As documentation doesn't say that.

Comment: You can't make a database on App Engine, as App Engine only host applications. Are you sure you are: connecting properly to Cloud SQL, with the proper library and configuration in Django, and you have the table in the Cloud SQL instance?